# Comment form browser validation

Tags: validation, comments, placeholder

For my Wordpress comment form I am using 'browser validation' by adding the following code to my functions.php:

```
/**
 * Enable form validation
 */
function custom_enable_comment_form_validation() {
    if ( comments_open() && current_theme_supports( 'html5' ) ) {
        echo '<script>document.getElementById("commentform").removeAttribute("novalidate");</script>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_enable_comment_form_validation' );
```

My comment form consists of a name and email field + a comment text field. All fields are required. Unfortunately, the 'required field' message only appears at the comment field... And when I fill in the comment field and leave the name and email field blank, Wordpress is still redirecting the user to the error page.

[An example of my comment form with a 'required field' message which need to pop-up if a field is blank. Unfortunately only the comment field is showing the message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg2Z5.png)
My comment form fields are also using placeholders and I found out when I removed the placeholder of the name and email field, all fields are working properly and are showing the pop-up messages. So the bug is most likely caused by the following code:

```
<?php
/* Using an placeholder in the name and email field. */
function my_update_comment_fields( $fields ) {

    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
    $req       = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
    $label     = $req ? '*' : ' ' . __( '(optional)', 'text-domain' );
    $aria_req  = $req ? "aria-required='true'" : '';

    $fields['author'] =
        '<p class="comment-form-author">
            <input id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( "Your name", "text-domain" ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
        '" size="30" ' . $aria_req . ' />
        </p>';

    $fields['email'] =
        '<p class="comment-form-email">
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( "Your email address", "text-domain" ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
        '" size="30" ' . $aria_req . ' />
        </p>';

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'my_update_comment_fields' );
?>
```

Unfortunately I can't find out where it is going wrong... can someone solve the problem?

Can someone also tell me how to change the text of the popup message to a default message in the functions.php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one who can solve this problem...?

Comment: Update: the problem is solved. Removing the "aria" tag from "aria-required" did the trick. I am still working on the last question; how to change the text of the popup messages. All help is welcome.